# Setup Function not working in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

when I am trying to add Setup: function in my TinyMCE javascript its converting my richtextbox to a simple textarea.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textArea',  // change this value according to your HTML
    menu: {
        edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall' },
        insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'link media | template hr' },
        format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic superscript subscript' },
        tools: { title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker code' }
    },
    resize: 'both',
    plugins: "wordcount",
    encoding: "xml",
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.onSaveContent.add(function (ed, o) {
            o.content = o.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
        });
    }
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
    <textarea id="content1" rows="2" cols="20" runat="server" ></textarea>
    <textarea id="content2" rows="2" cols="20" runat="server" ></textarea>
    <textarea id="content3" rows="2" cols="20" runat="server" ></textarea>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server"  OnClick="btnSave_Click"></asp:Button>

</div>
</form>
```

I dont know what is the issue, because without Setup: function, it's working absolutely fine.

Comment: Do you mean that TinyMCE appears and then when you click Save somewhere TinyMCE reverts to a textarea or when you have the setup function TinyMCE never appears?

Comment: I got the solution..I need to type this

Comment: setup: function (editor) {
                 editor.on('SaveContent', function (e) {
                     // console.log('SaveContent event', e);
                     e.content = e.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
                 });
             }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setup: function (editor) {
             editor.on('SaveContent', function (e) {
                 e.content = e.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
             });
         }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!